# DropWizard can't find field database (v 1.0.5)

Tags: dropwizard

My configuration isn't found by DropWizard, don't get it.

AppConfiguration class:

```
package se.test.app;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import io.dropwizard.Configuration;
import io.dropwizard.db.DataSourceFactory;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class AppConfiguration extends Configuration {
    @Valid
    @NotNull
    private DataSourceFactory database = new DataSourceFactory();

    @JsonProperty("database")
    public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory() {
        return database;
    }
}
```

And in `app.yaml`

```
database:
  driverClass: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  user: db_user
  password: db_password
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_db

  properties:
    charSet: UTF-8
    hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

But in terminal when running:

```
  * Unrecognized field at: database
    Did you mean?:
      - metrics
      - server
      - logging
```

Answer (score 4):

Include `dropwizard-jdbi` in your `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-jdbi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

See the [documentation of Dropwizard JDBI](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.5/docs/manual/jdbi.html).

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse:

Run > Run Configurations > Arguments :

"server {name of your yaml file}.yml"